# terminal stuck at “login” - blank screen (after installing oh-my-zsh, I think)

Tags: terminal, zsh, login, macos, oh-my-zsh

(I originally posted this on apple.stackexchange but then I found this one which is probably a better place)

I have a big problem. I've freshly installed mac os and was setting up my terminal. I installed iTerm, zsh and oh-my-zsh (following this tutorial, basically: https://medium.com/ayuth/iterm2-zsh-oh-my-zsh-the-most-power-full-of-terminal-on-macos-bdb2823fb04c)

After installing oh-my-zsh, I got this error message (this is just a random question showing that same error message):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61554566/how-to-avoid-bunch-of-oh-my-zsh-messages-showing-whenever-i-open-iterm-termi

I remember that the fix to this was running the suggested command (I've done this a few years ago):

`compaudit | xargs chmod g-w,o-w`

I think that was the last thing I did. Now every time I start a terminal (either Mac OS' `Terminal` or `iTerm`, doesn't matter) it gets stuck at "login" with a blank screen. I don't get any input prompt.

Even worse, I can't even shut down the mac anymore. When I click on shut down or restart, every app is closed and I see my wallpaper and nothing happens. I have to kill it via the power button.

After restarting, the terminal works perfectly again until I close it with `CMD-q`. Once I reopen it, it's stuck again at "login".

I've looked everywhere and can't find a solution.

I've seen this question (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267668/terminal-login-hangs) but it didn't help. I tried almost everything proposed there.

I would greatly appreciate any help or thoughts on this.

Also, it works when I boot into safe mode. There, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by `iTerm` having problems with the first beta version of `Mac OS Big Sur`. A specific setting causes the problems I've experienced. See https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/8965 for details.

Until fixed, the workaround is this (taken from the GitLab issue):

> Workaround:
> Disabling Enable session restoration under Preferences > Advanced > Session resolves prevents the hang ups, albeit with the obvious loss of functionality.

Note: A computer restart may be required before this change takes effect.

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to reproduce your issue, I cannot assert that this will fix it, but I'll put this out as something to try.

I suggest you try making the following configuration modification to `iTerm2`:

- Go to `Preferences`, then the `Profiles` tab at the top, then the `General` sub-tab
- Select your profile on the left, likely `Default`
- On the right, find the `Command` drop-down; it likely currently says "Login Shell"
- Change the `Command` to "Command"
- Enter the command `/bin/zsh --login`

With that configuration in place, close `iTerm2` and then start it again.  Does that yield a working environment?  If not, do you see any error messages?

If that doesn't help, then I suggest you rename `~/.zshrc` to something else (there's some way to get `Finder` to show dot files, but I don't remember how off the top of my head).  Then try again.

If none of the above helps, you might try switching your shell to `bash` long enough to debug the problem.  You'd follow the steps above, but change `/bin/zsh --login` to `/bin/bash --login`, then restart `iTerm2`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, it didn't change anything (the window's title changed from `login` to `zsh` but that's it). renaming the `.zshrc` also didn't work, sadly

Comment: @Quantm I added another suggestion on the end, give that a try and see if it helps at all.

Comment: Oh okay, now it's starting properly with the text "The default interactive shell is now zsh. To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`". This is a progress :D Thanks. Do you know how I now figure out what's causing the problem? Or what does the `/bin/zsh/ --login` command exactly do?

Comment: @Quantm Can once you get in with `bash`, can you manually run `zsh`?

Comment: Seems like it. Typing in `zsh` and pressing enter does work. I just get another prompt, it's not getting stuck.

Comment: @Quantm what about running `zsh --login`?

Comment: That still works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109934/discussion-between-andy-dalton-and-quantm).